# Firestore: Since transactions are purely canceled if the phone's Internet connexion goes off, can we use them to update money Firestore fields?

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-firestore

In Cloud Firestore, transactions are never executed if the phone's Internet connexion goes off (which could happen if the user passes through a tunnel, etc.).

My problem is that I store in this database the amount of something the user can buy... and he can also buy it again. So I want to update the existing amount in this way: `updated_amount = current_amount + new_amount`, `current_amount` and `updated_amount` being the same Firestore field in the Firestore document. That's why I should use transactions.

But since transactions can never occure (connexion to Internet goes off), should I actually use them?

I will use Google In-Apps API in a second time. For the moment, I just use Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use a transaction.  If the client is offline, the transaction will complete when going back online.  Just don't expect it to finish if the app process dies before the transaction finishes - it will not be retried.

Comment: "app process dies": you mean if I made a mistake in my code (not handled exception, etc.)?

Comment: Also, the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions says: "Transactions will fail when the client is offline.
" - are you sure transactions'd be retried in this case?

Comment: App processes can die for any number of reasons, such as the user leaving and not coming back.

Comment: Seems like you could test for yourself if the transaction truly fails when the app is offline.  In that case, you will just have to retry on your own.

Comment: Thanks again Doug!